# How can I add the ability to zoom in and out of tinymce 4 content?

Tags: tinymce-4

I can find a couple plugins that are compatible with tinymce 3 but none that are setup like tinymce 4 plugins. Is anyone aware of how to do this?

Comment: From the site rules: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." Sorry, but this is not the right site for this question.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and I appreciate your concern. I will edit the question to fit those parameters. Let me know if you have any concerns.